# csv to multi level json to create tree

Tags: json, csv

I have csv created from a menu

```
Main,Level 1,Level 2 ,Level 3,Level 4 
Forest,,,,
,lvl1link,,,
,,lvl2link,,
,,lvl2link2,,
Cloud,,,,
,clv1,,,
,,clvl2,,
,,clvl22,,
,,,clvl3,
,,,,clvl4
Energy,,,,
,enlvl1,,,
,enlvl11,,,
,,enlvl2,,
,,,enlvl3,
,,,enlvl31,
```

I got exported csv from another project and I need to create subsite and recreate menu structure.

How can I convert it to JSON where `Forest`  is parent of `lvl1link` and `lvl1link` is parent of `lvl2link`,  `lvl2link2` and so on.

In my mind it could be done by some recursive function.

example steps

- check index of first 2 rows which have value for `Main` element and note their index
- now iterate upto index of second row while looking for elements in col2 and note their index
- Build multidimensional array by repeating above steps for rest of the cols where following is returned

```php
array(
  'Forest' => array(
    'lvl1link' => array(
      'lvl2link',
      'lvl2link2'
    )
  ),
  'Cloud' => array(
    'clv1' => array(
      'clvl2',
      'clvl22' => array(
        'clvl3' => array(
          'clvl4'
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  'Energy' => array(
    'enlvl1',
    'enlvl11' => array(
      'enlvl2' => array(
        'enlvl3',
        'enlvl31'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I can work with php, python or javascript.

Please point me in right direction

Comment: It doesn't line up correctly if the `Main`, thru `Level 4` are keys. What language are you using? JSON and CSV are not languages. Read the section on [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The context and the goal are not clear to me, however I would go for a loading of your CSVs into database and then execute the proper queries to get joined results. For instance, [Talisman MPCS](https://talisman.alsego.com) solution is able to load csv into In-Memory SQL-enabled datastores and expose services to automatically produce query results as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to walk through the whole structure

```js
console.log(composify(`a\n,b`))
/* => [
  {
    el: ['a'],
    children: [
      {el: 'b'},
    ],
  }
]*/

function composify(arr, root = []) {
  if (!arr.push) arr = arr.split("\n").map(line => line.split(','));
  let p = null;
  arr.forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row.every(Boolean) && p) return;
    const cell = row[0]
    if (cell) {
        if (p) {
            p.children = composify(p.children);
        }
        p = {el: row.filter(Boolean), children: []};
        root.push(p)
        return;
    }
    p.children.push(row.slice(1))
  })
  if (p) p.children = composify(p.children)
  return root
}
```

```js
function composify(arr, root = []) {
  let p = null;
  arr.forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row.every(Boolean)) return;
    const cell = row[0]
    if (cell) {
        if (p) {
            p.children = composify(p.children);
        }
        p = {el: row.filter(Boolean), children: []};
        root.push(p)
        return;
    }
    p.children.push(row.slice(1))
  })
  if (p) p.children = composify(p.children)
  return root
}
function handle() {
  const vec2d = window.csv.value.split("\n").map(line => line.split(','));
  const tree = composify(vec2d)
  const str = JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2)
  console.log('str', str);
  window.json.textContent = str
}
handle()
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 600px;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
textarea, pre, .flex {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<textarea oninput="handle()" spellcheck="false" id="csv"
>Main,Level 1,Level 2 ,Level 3,Level 4 
Forest,,,,
,lvl1link,,,
,,lvl2link,,
,,lvl2link2,,
Cloud,,,,
,clv1,,,
,,clvl2,,
,,clvl22,,
,,,clvl3,
,,,,clvl4
Energy,,,,
,enlvl1,,,
,enlvl11,,,
,,enlvl2,,
,,,enlvl3,
,,,enlvl31,</textarea
>
<pre id="json"></pre>
</div>
```